# Android: how to scale xml imageview horizontally only

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

I've an imageview showing a 9 patch in a table cell that I want to work as a horizontal bar. However, I cannot get it to scale to fill the cell no matter what I try for width/height (match_parent, minWidth etc.). I can scale it to fill the whole cell with scale type 'FitXY'. How do I set the scaling to be FitX but leave the Y untouched?

Edit: Here's a simplified layout exhibiting my problem. It's a 2x2 table of images, with three copies of the default Android icon and one instance of my "bluebar" 9patch (imageView3) I want imageView3 to stretch horizontal to span the cell.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bluebar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout xml of your ImageView.